# Unexpected end of file error with every bash script I write

Tags: bash

I must be missing something here because no matter what bash compiler I use online and no matter what bash script I write I get the same `Unexpected end of file` error.

Here's my script

```
function hello { echo 'hello' } hello
```

I've also tried this

```
#!/bin/bash

hello_world () {
   echo 'hello, world'
}
```

> ```
> jdoodle.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
> jdoodle.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
> jdoodle.sh: line 3: `hello_world () {
> '
> ```

And this

```
#!/bin/bash
f() { $branchName = "branch" echo $branchName}; f

hello_world
```

I'm using this tool:

https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online/

Why can't I write a simple bash script?

Comment: `function hello { echo 'hello'; }; hello`

Comment: The closing brace must be preceded by a newline or a semicolon, as `}` is only special in command position. (Otherwise, it's parsed as just another argument of the current command.) It's not clear why your second example would fail.

Comment: The second one fails because there are embedded `\r` carriage returns that you can't see. I've added jdoodle's error message to make the problem clear.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a ; after your echo command. i just ran this on git bash, recieved the same error then looked at some documentation. After adding the semicolon it functioned perfectly.

```
function hello { echo 'Hello World!'; }
hello
```

Comment: Consider adding the reason for other two code segments as well, would answer the question completely. The second segment should work fine if ran as `dos2unix scriptname` and for 3rd one `f() { branchName="branch" ; echo $branchName; } ; f`.